# How to set up "Drude model" for Gromacs via git

Tags: git, github, compilation

I can install Gromacs any versions in Linux(Cent OS7):

```
$uncompression <download version>
$cd grommacs-5.0.7
$mkdir build
$ccmake..
$make 

'# make install
```

Then set up `.bashrc`

---

I want Drude model setup in Gromacs

http://mackerell.umaryland.edu/charmm_drude_ff.shtml

This homepage provide install "Drude model" for gromacs, and how to set up "Drude model" for gromacs via [git]

They are provide  below commands.

```
$git clone git://git.gromacs.org/gromacs.git
$cd gromacs
$git checkout drude
# Compile and install as you would any other (post-5.0) GROMACS version.
```

I am confused with this part between [`git checkout drude`] [complie & install as any other version].

I have to download files `<git drude file>` and `<gromacs file 5.0.7 version>`
How to compile and install as any other version, folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout drude` will checkout the [`origin/drude` branch](https://github.com/gromacs/gromacs/tree/drude).
See [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

Once you have done that, the files in your working tree (where you have cloned the repo) will be updated to reflect the content of that branch.

Then you can compile